# What is $\Lambda^{i}$ in the "Show that the highest weight of $\Lambda^{i}V $ is $\omega_{i}"$?

Tags: notation, lie-algebras

**Question:** What is $\Lambda^{i}$ in the "Show that the highest weight of $\Lambda^{i}V $ is $\omega_{i}$"?
In this question, $\omega_{i}$ are fundamental weights.

**Context:** Highest weight modules of simple Lie algebras.

I looked up the notation for $\Lambda^{i}$ in several textbooks, and I found a match in "Symmetries, Lie Algebras and Representations" by Jürgen Fuchs and Christoph Schweigert.
However, in that book the definition of $\Lambda^{i}$ is the Dynkin label of a highest weight of a finite-dimensional module corresponding to fundamental weight $\Lambda_{(i)}$.

However, since Dynkin labels are integers, it does not appear that $\Lambda^{i}$ are Dynkin labels in this case; otherwise $V$ would be simply multiplied by an integer.

Comment: It Means the $i$'th exterior power.

Comment: Tobias is right, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra or a book like Fulton and Harris *Representation Theory*.